# how to retrieve data from first letter

Tags: c#, sql, wildcard

hai how to do a command if user want to search a data by inserting the first letter. for example, if the first letter is c then it will display all data start from c? im still new in sql and asp, i have no idea to begin with.

Comment: You can always start searching for similar problems like https://www.bing.com/search?q=sql%20display%20all%20data%20start%20from%20letter... And than [edit] post with information you found (after trying things out and hitting concrete problem).

Comment: Part of the SQL will look something like this; where table.column LIKE 'c%'

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov thank you

Comment: @LittleDebugger thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Using Css**

The `::first-letter` selector is used to add a style to the first letter of the specified selector.

Note: The following properties can be used with ::first-letter:

**Snippet Example Below**

```css
p::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
```

```html
<p>My name is Donald.</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> For this selector you must specify the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:first-letter instead of ::first-letter).</p>
```